# Counting rules and probability

Tags: probability

A committee of 6 members is chosen from 7 engineers, 5 chemist and a doctor so as to consist at least 2 chemist, a doctor and at least an engineer but if one particular engineer and one particular chemist refuse to serve together on the same committee​, how many ways can this be done?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, kindly share your thoughts on this questions and specify where you are stuck?

Comment: As a suggestion, first solve the problem without the last constraint.  That should be entirely straight forward.  Then you might find it easier to count those combinations in which the two enemies do serve together.

Answer (score 1):

First we can observe that we are technically selecting 5 people from 5 chemists and 7 engineers as we have to have that one doctor no matter what. We can first count the total possible ways to select the remaining 5 people, then subtract the number of times that one pair of chemist and engineer who refuse to work together.

The number of ways to select 5 people is $$5*4*7*9*8$$
This is because we must first select at least two chemist, hence $5*4$, then select at least one engineer, hence the $7$. Then we are free to choose the remaining 9 for the last two spots, hence $9*8$

The number of ways where that one single bad pair occurs is $$1*1*4*9*8$$
This is because we are imposing the restriction of that one particular pair having to be selected, hence $1*1$. From here we see we already have one chemist and one engineer, hence we must select just one more chemist from the 4 remaining , hence the $4$. Then we are free to select the remaining 9, hence the $9*8$.

Knowing the total possibilities of selecting 5 such that there's at least two chemist and at least one engineer, and the possibilities that have that one pair that won't work, we can just subtract those two. Thus
$$5*4*7*9*8-1*1*4*9*8=9792$$
Our answer is 9792 total ways to select the 5 people